# Angular change in select causing strange behavior in $scope variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's the code in my view...

```
<label for="restaurant-type-select" class="control-label">
    Type
</label>
<select class="form-control" id="restaurant-type-select" ng-model="restaurant.type" ng-change="restaurantTypeChanged()">
    <option value="Franchise">Franchise</option>
    <option value="Corporate">Corporate</option>
    <option value="Individual">Individual</option>
</select>
<div ng-if="restaurant.type == 'Franchise' || restaurant.type == 'Corporate'">
    <label for="restaurant-group-select" class="control-label">
        Restaurant Group
    </label>
    <select class="form-control" id="restaurant-group-select" ng-model="restaurant.restaurant_group" ng-options="restaurant_group.name for restaurant_group in restaurant_groups.items track by restaurant_group.id">
    </select>
</div>
```

Here's the relevant controller code...

```
$scope.restaurantTypeChanged = function() {
    if ($scope.restaurant.type == "Individual") {
        $scope.restaurant.restaurant_group = {};
    }
    console.log($scope.restaurant.restaurant_group);
};
```

The purpose of this code is pretty simple.  If the restaurant.type is "Individual" there should be no restaurant_group set.  Otherwise, the restaurant_group should be visible and setable.  The problem is that the restaurant_group doesn't seem to stay set.

For example... My starting conditions are restaurant.type = "Corporate" and the restaurant.restaurant_group = { "id": 1, "name": "Something" }.  both select boxes show this correctly.  When I select "Individual" for the restaurant type, the restaurant group select box disappears and the console logs...

> {}

This is what I expect.  However, when I change the restaurant type back to "Corporate" the restaurant group select box reappears with the "Something" option already selected.  The console log immediately displays...

> {"id": 1, "name": "Something"}

This is not what I would expect.  I would expect the restaurant group to remain an empty object until I set it again with the restaurant group select box.  I'm obviously missing something that is going on here.

Comment: Can you create a plnkr for this ?

Answer (score 2):

I expect this is happening because `restaurant.restaurant_group` is bound to the `restaurant-group-select` inside your div with `ng-if="restaurant.type == 'Franchise' || restaurant.type == 'Corporate'"`.

So when you select a new restaurant type, the `ng-if` is resolving to true and `restaurant.restaurant_group` is picking up the default value from `restaurant-group-select` (usually the top one in the list).

Comment: I wonder if the unwanted behavior could be avoided by using ng-show instead of ng-if.

Answer (score 1):

Can you share Plnkr for this?

Its working for me. Please check.

`Plunkr`http://plnkr.co/edit/GUAJHc6n324zNdTTkbqL?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is due to ng-if..Try using ng-show in place ng-if

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.  The problem ended up being something besides my Angular code. We're using REST services on the backend.  The Angular code is changing the restaurant_group to an empty object.  Then it is updating the data and refreshing. I expected the backend to remove the restaurant_group if it was set to null or an empty object.  Instead it is simply ignoring that property.  So, on refresh the backend is repopulating the scope data.

Sorry if I wasted your time looking at this. Turns out that the Angular side of things is working just like it should.